# Cannot launch IntelliJ IDEA12 in Ubuntu 12 using desktop link

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I've created a desktop link to launch IDEA 12 in Unbutu 12. As soon as I am trying to launch the application using this link I am getting an error message: "cannot start Intellij IDEA. NO JDK found. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environmental variable points to valid JDK installation".

I can start IDEA  from the terminal navigating to the install directory and calling ./idea.sh
My configuration:
 Ubuntu 12.10
 Intellij IDEA 12.0.1
 Sun JDK 1.6.0_38
 IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME are defined in /etc/bash.bashrc
 JDK_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_38
 export JDK_HOME
 IDEA_JDK=/opt/jdk1.6.0_38
 export IDEA_JDK
 JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_38
 export JAVA_HOME
 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
 export PATH

they are properly displayed when running:
 echo $JDK_HOME  ->  /opt/jdk1.6.0_38
 echo $IDEA_JDK  ->  /opt/jdk1.6.0_38

From within IDEA this JDK recognized as a valid JDK under the same specified path.

Desktop linked was created using "Make link" command on the original idea.sh file and   copied to the desktop.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is the location of IDEA_JDK and JDK_HOME environmental variables. They have to be placed in  **/etc/profile** .

After defining of the environmental vars in  etc/profile there are several methods to create a desktop link:

1. As mentioned above by Roman Shevchenko

> Recommended way to integrate IDEA is to invoke Configure | Create Desktop Entry from welcome screen (or via Tools | Create Desktop Entry from main menu)

1. Invoke "Make Link" on ides.sh and move "link to idea.sh" to Desktop.

Answer (score 6):

Recommended way to integrate IDEA is to invoke Configure | Create Desktop Entry from welcome screen (or via Tools | Create Desktop Entry from main menu). After session restart you should be able to start IDEA from Dash menu, and pin it to the Unity launcher.

Answer (score 2):

To make the IDEA_JDK environment variable visible to processes that you start from your desktop rather than the shell, you need to define it in /etc/environment rather than in a .bashrc file.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I think that 
export IDEA_JDK
does the trick

Answer (score 1):

To make Intellij IDEA 12.1 work with Ubuntu 12.04+:

1> Create a file named: `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop`

2> Add this content to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=<YOUR-IDEA-FOLDER>/bin/idea.png
Exec="<YOUR-IDEA-FOLDER>/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

3> Reboot the system

Now you will have the best IDE fully working on your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just install java in System, even you setup `$JAVA_HOME`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

its will solve NO JDK found the issue. It solved my irritating desktop launcher issue.

Comment: Please do not post the same broad and probably non-helpful answer on multiple questions.